# Retain variable value in jQuery .each() function

Tags: jquery, find, each

I have a jQuery each function and set a variable called 'last_header' inside it, but only if the condition of a variable called 'header' isn't null. The problem I am having is every loop through the each function, the 'last_header' variable value isn't retained and is set to undefined. I want to retain the value of that variable the last time it was set.

```
$('#hidden_specs_' + i + ' tr').each(function() {
    var header = $(this).find('th').html();
    if (header !== null) {
        var last_header = $.trim(header); //THIS IS THE VARIABLE I WANT TO RETAIN ON THE NEXT LOOP THROUGH
    }
   alert(last_header); //THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED UNLESS IT HAS BEEN SET IN THIS LOOP

});
```

I hope that makes sense?

Any help would really be appreciated.

Many thanks,
Mark

Comment: Put `var last_header` before `.each()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because scope of the variable does not exists. You need set the variable as global outside each loop. something like this:

```
var last_header = "";
$('#hidden_specs_' + i + ' tr').each(function() {
var header = $(this).find('th').html();
if (header !== null) {
    last_header = $.trim(header); //THIS IS THE VARIABLE I WANT TO RETAIN ON THE NEXT LOOP THROUGH
}
alert(last_header); 
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kx5yndrL/)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Milind. Yeah I had actually tried that previously but it didn't work. I have tried it again but I am still getting undefined for the last_header variable.

Comment: try giving alert in if condition. see what value is set.

Comment: It works as intended. The correct value is displayed but only if header isn't null.

Comment: @markwilliamsweb: you have redefined the variable again. it should be only global. http://jsfiddle.net/kx5yndrL/

Answer (score 1):

you can use the HTML5 Custom Attributes to achieve the functionality. I have updated your code as below:

```
$('#hidden_specs_' + i + ' tr').each(function() {
var header = $(this).find('th').html();
if (header !== null) {
    var last_header = $.trim(header); 
    $("body").data("last_header",$.trim(header)); // but if your condition satisfies then the value will be overridden.
}  

alert($("body").data("last_header")); //THIS IS THE LINE WHICH WILL GIVE YOUR LAST SET VALUE
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Super, that works thank you very much. I don't understand why the other method provided didn't work though.

Comment: other solutions will also work, just change that if condition to `if (header !== undefined) {` and try out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable outside the loop

```
//declare the variable outside the loop
var last_header;
$('#hidden_specs_' + i + ' tr').each(function () {
    var header = $(this).find('th').html();
    if (header !== null) {
        last_header = $.trim(header); //THIS IS THE VARIABLE I WANT TO RETAIN ON THE NEXT LOOP THROUGH
    }
    alert(last_header); //THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED UNLESS IT HAS BEEN SET IN THIS LOOP

});
alert(last_header);
```

In your case, the variables scope is limited to the `each` callback function so the variable will not be available outside the loop.